# Scala Future[A] and Future[Option[B]] composition

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I have an app that manages `Item`s. When the client queries an item by some `info`, the app first tries to find an existing item in the db with the info. If there isn't one, the app would

1. Check if `info` is valid. This is an expensive operation (much more so than a db lookup), so the app only performs this when there isn't an existing item in the db.
2. If `info` is valid, insert a new `Item` into the db with `info`.

There are two more classes, `ItemDao` and `ItemService`:

```
object ItemDao {
  def findByInfo(info: Info): Future[Option[Item]] = ...

  // This DOES NOT validate info; it assumes info is valid
  def insertIfNotExists(info: Info): Future[Item] = ...
}

object ItemService {
  // Very expensive
  def isValidInfo(info: Info): Future[Boolean] = ...

  // Ugly
  def findByInfo(info: Info): Future[Option[Item]] = {
    ItemDao.findByInfo(info) flatMap { maybeItem =>
      if (maybeItem.isDefined)
        Future.successful(maybeItem)
      else
        isValidInfo(info) flatMap {
          if (_) ItemDao.insertIfNotExists(info) map (Some(_))
          else Future.successful(None)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The `ItemService.findByInfo(info: Info)` method is pretty ugly. I've been trying to clean it up for a while, but it's difficult since there are three types involved (`Future[Boolean]`, `Future[Item]`, and `Future[Option[Item]]`). I've tried to use `scalaz`'s `OptionT` to clean it up but the non-optional `Future`s make it not very easy either.

Any ideas on a more elegant implementation?

Comment: Have you looked at `lift`ing your non `Option` futures into the monad transformer?

Comment: @badcook Can you go into a bit more details?

Comment: @badcook I see what you mean. Do I have to write the lifting function myself (which is trivial) or can use existing scalaz functions?

Comment: Scalaz should have a `.liftM[OptionT]` method you can call (you'll probably need the type annotation to help Scala's typechecker out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need scalaz for this. Just break your `flatMap` into two steps:
first, find and validate, then insert if necessary. Something like this:

```
ItemDao.findByInfo(info).flatMap { 
    case None => isValidInfo(info).map(None -> _)
    case x => Future.successful(x -> true)
}.flatMap { 
  case (_, true) => ItemDao.insertIfNotExists(info).map(Some(_))
  case (x, _) => Future.successful(x)
}
```

Doesn't look too bad, does it? If you don't mind running validation in parallel with retrieval (marginally more expensive resource-vise, but likely faster on average), you could further simplify it like this:

```
ItemDao
  .findByInfo(info)
  .zip(isValidInfo(info))
  .flatMap {
    case (None, true) => ItemDao.insertIfNotExists(info).map(Some(_))
    case (x, _) => x
  }
```

Also, what does `insertIfNotExists` return if the item does exist? If it returned the existing item, things could be even simpler:

```
 isValidInfo(info)
   .filter(identity)
   .flatMap { _ => ItemDao.insertIfNotExists(info) }
   .map { item => Some(item) }  
   .recover { case _: NoSuchElementException => None }
```

Comment: I think all the answers are great elegant solutions, but yours are the most lightweight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment.

Since you've already indicated a willingness to go down the route of monad transformers, this should do what you want. There is unfortunately quite a bit of line noise due to Scala's less than stellar typechecking here, but hopefully you find it elegant enough.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object ItemDao {
  def findByInfo(info: Info): Future[Option[Item]] = ???

  // This DOES NOT validate info; it assumes info is valid
  def insertIfNotExists(info: Info): Future[Item] = ???
}

object ItemService {
  // Very expensive
  def isValidInfo(info: Info): Future[Boolean] = ???

  def findByInfo(info: Info): Future[Option[Item]] = {
    lazy val nullFuture = OptionT(Future.successful(none[Item]))
    lazy val insert = ItemDao.insertIfNotExists(info).liftM[OptionT]
    lazy val validation = 
      isValidInfo(info)
        .liftM[OptionT]
        .ifM(insert, nullFuture)
    val maybeItem = OptionT(ItemDao.findByInfo(info))
    val result = maybeItem <+> validation
    result.run
  }
}
```

Two comments about the code:

- We are using the `OptionT` monad transformer here to capture the `Future[Option[_]]` stuff and anything that just lives inside `Future[_]` we're `liftM`ing up to our `OptionT[Future, _]` monad.
- `<+>` is an operation provided by `MonadPlus`. In a nutshell, as the name suggests, `MonadPlus` captures the intuition that often times monads have an intuitive way of being combined (e.g. `List(1, 2, 3) <+> List(4, 5, 6) = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`). Here we're using it to short-circuit when `findByInfo` returns `Some(item)` rather than the usual behavior to short-circuit on `None` (this is roughly analogous to `List(item) <+> List() = List(item)`).

Other small note, if you actually wanted to go down the monad transformers route, often times you end up building everything in your monad transformer (e.g. `ItemDao.findByInfo` would return an `OptionT[Future, Item]`) so that you don't have extraneous `OptionT.apply` calls and then `.run` everything at the end.

Comment: Does the `<+>` works the same as `orElse` in this case?

Comment: Yep that's one way of thinking about it. Indeed the applicative functor equivalent of `MonadPlus` is often suggestively named `Alternative` for precisely that reason. EDIT: Whoops you're talking about Scala's actual `orElse` method. Yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with path-dependent type and higher-kinded type, something like the following can be an elegant solution:

```
type Const[A] = A

sealed trait Request {
  type F[_]
  type A
  type FA = F[A]

  def query(client: Client): Future[FA]
}

case class FindByInfo(info: Info) extends Request {
  type F[x] = Option[x]
  type A = Item

  def query(client: Client): Future[Option[Item]] = ???
}

case class CheckIfValidInfo(info: Info) extends Request {
  type F[x] = Const[x]
  type A = Boolean

  def query(client: Client): Future[Boolean] = ???
}

class DB {
  private val dbClient: Client = ???
  def exec(request: Request): request.FA = request.query(dbClient)
}
```

What this does is basically to abstract over both the wrapper type (eg. `Option[_]`) as well as inner type. For types without a wrapper type, we use `Const[_]` type which is basically an identity type.

In scala, many problems alike this can be solved elegantly using Algebraic Data Type and its advanced type system (i.e path-dependent type & higher-kinded type). Note that now we have single point of entry `exec(request: Request)` for executing db requests instead of something like DAO.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean, but I still can't see how this would make composing requests easier. How can the case classes avoid the `map`/`flatMap` chaos in the current implementation of `ItemService.findByInfo`?

Comment: Ah I must have misread your question. Aside from some syntactic sugars, I don't have a better answer. I personally think lifting into OptionT is too much noises. But YMMV ;)